# Better way to write the following code in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming

I've this following function, which maps ids to a list of Strings

```
private fun doIdMapping(resourcesList: List<String>): List<Pair<Int, String>>  {
    var id = 4

    return resourcesList.map { resource -> 
        id++
        id to resource
    }
}
```

The id starts from 5 as you can see here. I can make this code look cleaner if id started from 0. Just like this

```
private fun doIdMapping(resourcesList: List<String>): List<Pair<Int, String> = resourcesList.mapIndexed { index, resource -> 
    index to resource
}
```

Is there some Kotlin function to achieve the first result without the use of var id. Maybe some function whose index starts at 5?

Comment: just put `index + 4` in your second code snippet

Comment: @al3c you should write this as an answer

Comment: `index + 5`, right? But yes, we're offsetting an index. It can't get any cleaner or concise than this.

Comment: Your first version of the code could be more concise using `++id to resource`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I forgot that I could do that! facepalm. I guess this is already solved then. Thanks @al3c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment by [@al3c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6962183/al3c)

```
private fun doIdMapping(resourcesList: List<String>): List<Pair<Int, String> = resourcesList.mapIndexed { index, resource -> 
    index + 5 to resource
}
```

This was probably easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip function and int-range:

```
    private fun doIdMapping(resourcesList: List<String>, startIndex: Int = 5) 
         = (startIndex..startIndex + resourcesList.size).zip(resourcesList)
```